# Use of approximately only in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the use of "approximately only" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> In other words, both tip leakage flow and endwall boundary layer flow
>   have a high effect on the total pressure drop across the turbine at
>   high flow coefficients while the turbine torque **approximately only** is
>   dependent on the tip leakage flow at high flow coefficients.

explanation:

1. "only"= more/increased emphasis
2. "approximately"= The tip leakage flow and endwall boundary layer flow reduce the turbine torque. But the effect of tip leakge flow is much higher than that of endwall boundary layer flow on the torque at high flow coefficients.

Comment: It's grammatical in itself, but it feels like there's a mistake in that sentence somewhere.

Comment: My meaning of " high effect" is "significant effect".

Comment: What is the source? I suppose this might be normal in such a complex discussion, but if you wrote it you might consider breaking the content down into shorter less complex statements.

Comment: It feels like this sentence would make more sense if the two-word phrase was worded as "only approximately" instead of "approximately only".

Comment: @user19061: That wasn't my issue, but "significant" is much better in that context.

Comment: @J.R.: I think you could go further and include the copula in the reordering: "is only approximately" instead of "approximately only is" ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "approximately only" is natural in this way. I would write:

> In other words, both tip leakage flow and endwall boundary layer flow have a high effect on the total pressure drop across the turbine at high flow coefficients, while the turbine torque is **more closely** dependent on the tip leakage flow at high flow coefficients.

Adding a comma after the first "coefficients" helps one's understanding, since this is such a long sentence with lots of nested phrases.

Comment: What is your exact meaning of "more closely"?

Comment: *more* = *only* (as you wrote). As for *closely*, see [*close*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/close) def. 6. Based on my non-technical knowledge in such matters, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a mess.

- I think "approximately only" should be replaced by "somewhat".
- I think the somewhat (aka "approximately only") should be after the "is":
- "High flow coefficients" is mentioned twice.  Only once is fine.
- Throw in a few determiners.

"In other words, at high flow coefficients both the tip leakage flow and the endwall boundary layer flow have a substantial effect on the total pressure drop across the turbine while the turbine torque is somewhat dependent on the tip leakage flow."

This at least makes sense to me.